# insert key like "vrf.www" in a mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert data with key "." like ['V1362:S.P.T'] but it will give me error,document to insert contains invalid key: keys cannot contain ".": "V1362:S.P.T", i am using mongo version v3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `.` in the field name. Take a look into [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names).

> Field names can contain dots (i.e. .) and dollar signs (i.e. $).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names

Might be an option would be to replace `.` to `_` or something else.